# Insert into not working in oracle when a single column has more characters

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have created a table as:

```
CREATE TABLE SHOP.EMPLOYEES
(
    EMPLOYEEID NUMBER(11)         NOT NULL,
    LASTNAME   VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) DEFAULT NULL,
    FIRSTNAME  VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) DEFAULT NULL,
    BIRTHDATE  DATE               DEFAULT NULL,
    PHOTO      VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) DEFAULT NULL,
    NOTES      VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

I have column `notes` which has more than 100 characters.So,I tried is:

```
INSERT INTO shop.employees (EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, BirthDate, Photo, Notes) 
VALUES (1, 'Davolio', 'Nancy', '1968-12-08', 'EmpID1.pic', 'Education includes a BA in psychology from Colorado State University. She also completed (The Art of the Cold Call). Nancy is a member of Toastmasters International.')
```

But I am getting an error:

> Error at line 1
>   ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

What could be the best datatype for those long text in Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1968-12-08` is string and you need to insert date in your table.

Conversion of string to date is needed in whenever dates are used.

There are two ways to convert your string to date.

1. `DATE '1968-12-08'`
2. `TO_DATE('1968-12-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`

Cheers!!

Comment: after changing date to to_date i got this error: : ORA-12899: value too large for column "SHOP"."EMPLOYEES"."NOTES" (actual: 165, maximum: 100)

Comment: @KarkiAshwin Your notes column is only 100 bytes and you are trying to insert 165 characters. Reduce the size of notes to 100 characters. See below answers.

Comment: @KarkiAshwin I'd say the *"ORA-12899: value too large for column"* error is pretty self-explanatory. It means you have fixed the problem with the date and moved on the next issue.

Answer (score 1):

`BIRTHDATE` is a DATE, not a varachar, so you need to convert it:

```
to_date('1968-12-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Comment: after changing date to to_date i got this error: : ORA-12899: value too large for column "SHOP"."EMPLOYEES"."NOTES" (actual: 165, maximum: 100)

Comment: @KarkiAshwin error is pretty clear, you are trying to insert 165 characters, while definition is up to 100

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you can't expect to put something as long as 300 characters into something that accepts 100 characters, can you?

But, that's not your problem. Date is. The 4th column is `birthdate`, its datatype is `date`, but you are inserting a **string** into it, because `'1968-12-08'` **is** a string. You should have used a date literal instead, i.e. `date '1968-12-08'`.

Oh, yes - back to your original question (although a wrong one in this context): *best datatype for a long text*. You can create a column whose datatype is `VARCHAR2(4000)` and it'll happily accept that "long" string you used. Or, you can even choose a `CLOB` which accepts up to 4 giga of characters; more than enough for you, I presume.

Finally, your query:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES
  2  (
  3    EMPLOYEEID  NUMBER(11)                        NOT NULL,
  4    LASTNAME    VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)                DEFAULT NULL,
  5    FIRSTNAME   VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)                DEFAULT NULL,
  6    BIRTHDATE   DATE                              DEFAULT NULL,
  7    PHOTO       VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)                DEFAULT NULL,
  8    NOTES       VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)                DEFAULT null
  9  );

Table created.
```

Note date literal in line #4 as well as substr function in line #5 (which restricted string length to 100).

```
SQL> INSERT INTO employees
  2    (EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, BirthDate, Photo, Notes)
  3  VALUES
  4    (1, 'Davolio', 'Nancy', date '1968-12-08', 'EmpID1.pic',
  5     substr('Education includes a BA in psychology from Colorado State University. She also completed (The Art of the Cold Call). Nancy is a member
 of Toastmasters International.', 1, 100))
  6  ;

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I suggest simply make the `NOTES` column larger:

```
ALTER TABLE SHOP.EMPLOYEES
  MODIFY (NOTES VARCHAR2(4000));
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0425faaec21a89d99e22dd4d9eb51bc3)

If you need something larger than this you could use the `CLOB` data type.